# Pass vector of derived class pointers to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, vector

I have a Base class with Derived1 and Derived2 derived classes and a Consumer class.

I want to create a vector of Base pointers with the two derived class objects to then pass to the consumer class so it can get derived class details using

```
pointervec.at(0).i
```

I've been stuck on this for ages and cannot get it to work. This is a simplified version of what I have. I'm concerned about the syntax around creating the vector, passing it to the thread and accessing different indexes.

```
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
    void dosomething() {cout<<i<<endl;}
    int i;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() {i = 5;}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() {i = 10;}
};

class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer();
    void dostuff( vector<Base> &pointervec) {cout<<5<<endl;}
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    Derived1 derived1;
    Derived2 derived2;

    vector<Base*>pointervec;
    pointervec.push_back(&derived1);
    pointervec.push_back(&derived2);

    std::thread t1(&Derived1::dosomething, &derived1);
    std::thread t2(&Derived2::dosomething, &derived2);
    std::thread t3(&Consumer::dostuff, ref(pointervec));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Comment: `vector<Base>` is not `vector<Base*>`

Comment: Your example is probably too simplified from the real code you have. Why do you actually need a `vector<Base>&` type for `dostuff()`, instead of that `vector<Base*>` that you're passing around?

Comment: my consumer class needs to accept a range of derived classes, so to make it work with any derived class, I use Base pointers.

I have used an array of pointers before

    Ranger * ptrarray[3];   
    ptrarray[0]=&derived1;
    ptrarray[1]=&derived2;
    ptrarray[2]=&derived3;

and accessed in my consumer using 

    ptrarray[i]->variable.

but now I want to make it flexible to work with any number of classes.

Comment: @acv17 to elaborate on Mike's comment, pay attention to the type of  `pointervec` argument of `Consumer::dostuff` and compare with the type that you pass to the thread.

Comment: @acv17 I still don't get why `doStuff()` needs a `vector<Base>`, and what cannot be satisfied in there using `vector<Base*>` there.

Comment: The real world scenario is I have a bunch of data producers and they all have a range of specific parameters saved as variables in each derived class. I'd post the code but it is huge.

The consumer needs to make decisions on this data based on these variables, so it needs to grab the variables from each of the derived classes using the pointer->variable operator.

as I said, this worked really well with the array, but I want to make it flexible, and cannot get the syntax correct for vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your example work, there are a few mistakes that need to be corrected.

1. As `Consumer::doStuff` is a non-static member function, you need an instance of `Consumer` to run it on.
2. Because of above, `Consumer` needs a defined constructor
3. The signature of `doStuff` needs to take a (reference to a) vector of `Base` pointers, not `Base` objects
4. Thread `t3` needs said instance of `Consumer` as its first forwarded parameter (to provide the `this` parameter.

Final working code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
    void dosomething() {cout<<i<<endl;}
    int i;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() {i = 5;}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2() {i = 10;}
};

class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer() {}
    void dostuff( vector<Base*> &pointervec) {cout<<pointervec.at(0)->i<<endl;}
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    Derived1 derived1;
    Derived2 derived2;

    Consumer c;
    vector<Base*>pointervec;
    pointervec.push_back(&derived1);
    pointervec.push_back(&derived2);

    std::thread t1(&Derived1::dosomething, &derived1);
    std::thread t2(&Derived2::dosomething, &derived2);
    std::thread t3(&Consumer::dostuff, &c, ref(pointervec));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Comment: I edited above code to give it this function body. Works perfectly fine, as per [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61bbe0e80ea1cdaf)

Comment: you are a legend!
Thank you very much. Truly helpful.